# How do I make a lagged value variable from an existing column?

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a variable which is a 1 day lag of data in a specific column.

I have previously done this successfully in a data set that had the variables: Date, Country, Protest, Riot, shutdown. I was able to use the code below to create the variable "lag.value"which pulled from the shutdown values.

```
DT[, lag.value:=c(NA, shutdown[-.N]), by=Country].
```

However, now I have a similar data set that also has region data for each country: Date, Country, Region, Protest, Riot, shutdown. The lag value is shifting outside of the country and region the shutdown was originally affiliated with.

A sample dataset:

```
     DT <- data.table(Date = as.Date(c("2019-01-01", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-03", "2019-01-03", "2019-01-03", "2019-01-04" )),
             Country = c("India","India","India","Pakistan","Pakistan", "Cameroon", "India"),
             Region = c('Kashmir', 'Rajasthan', 'Punjab', 'Islamabad', 'National', 'Nord-Ouest', "Kashmir"),
             Protest = c(4,2,0,1,4,1,0 ),
             Riot = c(0,2,1,1,4,1,1 ),
             Shutdown = c(1,0,1,1,0,1,1),
             lag.shutdown = c(1,0,1,1,0,1,1))
DT <- DT %>% group_by(Country, Region) %>% complete(Date = seq(min(.$Date), max(.$Date), by = 'day'))
DT <- as.data.table(DT)
DT[, lag.value:=c(NA, Shutdown[-.N]), by = Region]
```

I have also tried using:

```
  DT %>% 
    dplyr::mutate_at(c("ShutdownCopy"), by = DT$Region, funs(lag), n = 1)
```

But that did not work in my actual data. I am having a hard time reproducing the problem in the sample data.

In my actual data, after creating the lag.value. Line 3 has a shutdown for Morocco in the nationwide region on 2/16/16. So, line 17, should have 1 in the lag value column, but does not.

```
Date_Start  Country Region                       Demonstration  Shutdown    lag.value
 1  2/16/16 Morocco Rabat - Sale - Kenitra       0              0          0
 2  2/16/16 Morocco Guelmim - Oued Noun          0              0          0
 3  2/16/16 Morocco Nationwide                   0              1          0
 4  2/16/16 Morocco Oriental                     0              0          0
 5  2/16/16 Morocco Marrakech - Safi             0              0          0
15  2/17/16 Morocco Rabat - Sale - Kenitra       0              0          0
16  2/17/16 Morocco Guelmim - Oued Noun          0              0          0
17  2/17/16 Morocco Nationwide                   0              0          0
```

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: It's very hard to know what you want here as, as you said, the code/example data you have given does not result in an error. Does it give what you want but it doesn't work for your full data? Or isn't that what you want? You might need to find the part of your data causing the problem rather than providing an example that doesn't return the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha, I understand what you have done here. I think your steps must have been as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(
  Date = as.Date(c("2019-01-01", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-03", "2019-01-04" )),
  Country = c("India","India","India","Pakistan","Pakistan"),
  Region = c('Kashmir', 'Rajasthan', 'Punjab', 'Islamabad', 'National'),
  Demonstrations = c(4,2,0,1,4),
  Shutdown = c(1,0,1,1,1),
  ShutdownCopy = c(1,0,1,1,1)
)
DT <- DT %>% group_by(Country, Region) %>% 
  tidyr::complete(Date = seq(min(.$Date), max(.$Date), by = 'day'))
```

Then you tried the following (mind the cases!)

```
DT[, lag.value:=c(NA, Shutdown[-.N]), by=Country]
```

Then you get the error. Why? Let's try the following line:

```
class(DT)
[1] "grouped_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

See, there's the culprit. Once you subject it to a dplyr chain, it no longer is a `data.table`. If you leave out the `tidyr::complete` and just do the grouping, it will also give you the same result.

If you do

```
DT <- as.data.table(DT)
DT[, lag.value:=c(NA, Shutdown[-.N]), by=Country]
```

Then voila!

I am also an extensive `tidyverse` user and sometimes going back and forth with `data.table` is confusing. Always check your classes if you tend to unconsciously use the pipes. There is also a great cheat sheet [here](https://ugoproto.github.io/ugo_r_doc/datatable.pdf).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, that solved the error issue. but, the lag value is still associating with the wrong observations.

Comment: I just realized, "Nationwide" is a Region category that more than one country has. Could this be screwing things up? If so, is there syntax that will make lag.value generation look at more than just by = Country, or by = Region?